# How to get predecessor of a church numeral

Tags: sml, church-encoding

I'm practicing with SML and I'm doing a small assignment where we have to implement Church numerals defined as:

```
datatype 'a church = C of ('a -> 'a) * 'a  -> 'a
```

example val

```
ZERO = C(fn (f,x) => x)
```

I have already implemented the functions:

```
create: int -> 'a church  
churchToInt: 'a church -> int
```

and `SUC` which returns the successor of a Church numeral.

Now I have to implement the function

```
PRED: 'a church -> 'a church * 'a church
```

which returns the tuple of (predecessor, current numeral). I am not allowed to use `churchToInt`, I should directly work with Church numerals. Apparently this is solvable in one line by passing a specific argument.

I was thinking of just using `SUC` over and over until we hit the right number but there is no way for me to compare the 2 Church numerals. I am completely stuck on this.

Comment: if this is homework, you should tag it as such

Answer (score 2):

suppose you want to construct the function that give you the pred of **N**.
 You have to use pairs on numbers 
like this (0,1) (1,2) ....(n,n+1)
and construct the `succPair` function 
to go from (n-1,n) to (n,n+1)
and then you apply `succPair` **N** times on (0,1)
and last step you just apply `snd` on the last result I described
 and then boom! you get your pred of **N** 
look here to get the picture http://m2-info-upmc.blogspot.fr/2012/11/predecesseur-sur-les-entiers-de-church.html

Answer (score -2):

You must have forced it to by an int in your subPred.